# Sum of integers with tuples inside a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tuples

I'm trying to return the sum of all elements on a set of tuples inside tuples, but the last value is always `None`, so I get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

using the code below.

How do I skip this last value?

It has to be done with recursion.

```
L = (1, (2, (3, None)))

def sum(L):
    if not L:
        return None
    else:
        return L[0] + sum(L[1])
```

Comment: `return 0` ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is really the structure of your tuple, just return zero when you reach the end:

```
def my_sum(L):
    if not L:
        return 0
    else:
        return L[0] + my_sum(L[1])
```

And don't shadow the name of a built-in. It's bad practice, even if it's technically legal.

Also, I don't think this is necessarily a good candidate for recursion. An iterative solution works the same, and without creating a new stack frame for every level:

```
s = 0
while L:
    s += L[0]
    L = L[1]
```

That's just a personal bonus for when you can make the design decision.

Comment: Side-note: Probably ought to suggest a change from `if not L:`/`while L:` to `if L is None:`/`while L is not None:`, so you don't spuriously stop summing if one of the values happens to be `0`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. The second value is explicitly either a tuple or None in the question, but I agree with the general intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [117]: L = (1, (2, (3, None)))
     ...:
     ...: def sum(L):
     ...:     if not L:
     ...:         return 0
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return L[0] + sum(L[1])
     ...:

In [118]: sum(L)
Out[118]: 6
```